# Find a matrix $B$ so that $A=BB^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[refer to this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555699/find-a-matrix-b-so-that-a-bbt)

I have matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&2&2\\2&3&2\\2&2&7\end{pmatrix}$ ,
$D=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&9\end{pmatrix}$ and
$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&1&1\\0&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$

By $B\equiv P\sqrt{D}$, I got $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&1&1\\0&-1&2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\sqrt3&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$

So $B= \begin{pmatrix}1&\sqrt3&3\\-1&\sqrt3&3\\0&-\sqrt3&6\end{pmatrix} $

However when I plug $B$ into $BB^T$ I didn’t get the matrix $A$.

Comment: Does $A=PDP^{T}$ or something?

Comment: @T.J.Gaffney It doesn’t, though, and that’s the crux of the problem.

Comment: $P^{-1}AP=D$ is given, Are they equivalent?

Comment: @BrianWu.  $BB^T=PDP^T$ with how you've defined $B$.  This doesn't equal $A$, with how you've defined $P$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo its $B$, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $P$ isn't orthogonal. Sure, the columns are all pairwise orthogonal, but the rows aren't. Or, more pecisely, the columns are orthogonal but not orthonormal. This doesn't make $A = PDP^{-1}$ an incorrect diagonalisation, but does mean that $A \neq PDP^T$, as $P^{-1}\neq P^T$.

You need to make each column of $P$ into a *unit vector*. Which is to say, you need
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt6}\\
-\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac1{\sqrt6}\\
0&-\frac1{\sqrt3}&\frac2{\sqrt6}\end{pmatrix}
$$
This way we actually *do* have $P^{-1} = P^T$, which means that $A = PDP^{-1}$ is indeed equal to $PDP^T$, and your $B = P\sqrt D$ will work.

Comment: $P$ is formed from the three eigenvectors of A and $P$ is supposed to be orthogonal

Comment: @BrianWu Yes, you're right, it is supposed to be orthogonal. Note, however, that an orthogonal matrix doesn't just mean that the columns are orthogonal (that happens automatically with a symmetric matrix with distinct eigenvalues). An orthogonal matrix is alos required to have _unit length_ columns. You will note that in my $P$, the columns are still eigenvectors. They are, in fact, the _same_ eigenvectors, just scaled down so that they all have length $1$.

Comment: @BrianWu Note that, somewhat confusingly, an orthogonal matrix is not just required to have orthogonal columns, but *orthonormal* ones. So although your matrix has orthogonal columns, it is not an orthogonal matrix, since the columns aren't orthonormal.

Answer (score 0):

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 3 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 27 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 27 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 2 & 2 \\ 
2 & 3 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

One way to finish from $ Q^T D Q = H  ,$ is to force the middle to be the identity matrix, so $R$ soves $D = R^T R,  $ then $H = Q^T R^T RQ.$   Might as well take $R$ diagonal, the square roots of the diagonal elements in $D.$ Note that my $Q$ has determinant $1,$  so

$$  
RQ = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\sqrt 3 &  \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt 3 }  \\ 
0 & \frac{\sqrt 5}{ \sqrt 3} &  \frac{ 2 }{ \sqrt {15} }  \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{\sqrt 5} \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For you, the matrix on the right is $B^T,$ so $B^T = RQ$ and $B = (RQ)^T$